# Why getting class in Kotlin using double-colon (::)?

Tags: java, operators, kotlin

We know that double-colon (`::`) is used to get function (callable) reference in Kotlin, e.g. `String::compareTo`, `"string"::compareTo`.

In Java we use `SomeClass.class` and `someInstance.getClass()` to get the class. Why in Kotlin we use `SomeClass::class` and `someInstance::class` while `class` is not a function/method?

```
println(String::compareTo)
// output: fun kotlin.String.compareTo(kotlin.String): kotlin.Int
println("string".compareTo("strong"))
// output: -6
println(String::class)
// output: class kotlin.String
println("string".class)
// compile error
```

Comment: Double-colon is for reflect(class, method, field) in kotlin, not method reference like in java.

Comment: Thanks, that's something I misunderstood from the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html). I thought it's callable reference, since `val f: () -> CharArray = ""::toCharArray` is valid.

Comment: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/class-literals-in-kotlin/465/7

Comment: @Miha_x64 's answer is the answer, thanks; as I asked about "why" instead of "how"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`::` in Kotlin is about meta-programming, including method references, property references and class literals.
See [discussion about class literals](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/class-literals-in-kotlin/465).

Answer (score 50):

In Kotlin you can write [`Object::class`](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references), which will give you a [`KClass`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html). KClass is not equivalent to the class Class that we know from Java. 
If you want to get the Java Class class you can write `Object::class.java` - i.e.:
`println("string"::class.java)`

Also in java, `.class` is not a method or a member - it is a special directive for the compiler to access the class.
I guess each language select the syntax that makes most sense for it, and kotlin's creators decided to use `::`

Comment: why doesn't the language implemented getKClass() instead? and accordingly getJavaClass()???!

Comment: maybe they didn't want to be so influenced by Java :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was "why"

Comment: @mjaggard Well, I think the answer at least partly explains why, because it explains why it *wouldn't* make sense to simply copy Java's syntax: namely because Kotlin's `Object::class` is not equivalent to Java's `Object.class` and evaluates to a value of a different type. The two answers here are nicely complementary: this one answers the question "why not Java's syntax?" and [Miha_x64's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49938744/1709587) answers "given Java's syntax is ruled out, why pick `::` out of all the conceivable alternatives?"; together, they're a full answer.