# Getting the name of a static member property in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I have a javaclass like this, inside of a Kotlin project:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final String FOO = "HelloWorld";
  public static final String ALT_FOO = "HelloWorldAlt";
}
```

How can I get a String with the value `FOO`? (not the value of the field, the name of the field)

i.e. `val theName = "FOO"`

For example later on I will have a map.

```
val map = mapOf("FOO" to "HelloWorldAlt", "BAR" to "CoronaGotMeInside")
```

and I want to do the below:

```
val result = map[theName]
println(result)
// HelloWorldAlt
```

I know I can get all the field values like the below, but I can't figure how to get the static member variable name off of a single static var. I don't want to iterate all staticProperties. I want to explicitly look one up.

```
val notResult = BuildConfig::class.staticProperties.filter { it.name == "FOO" }[0].getter.call()
println(notResult)
// HelloWorld
```

As an example of a not iterative solution, I want something like this:

```
val theName = BuildConfig.FOO::variableName() // Totally made up, but I want to act on the singular constant, not on a collection
```

This would allow me to have some compile time confidence when using the variables name a map key. Crazy I know.

Comment: `BuildConfig::FOO.name`

Comment: HA! unbelievable, so much googling and I couldn't find that. Thanks stick it as an answer (and a link to the docs if you have it) and I'll mark as answered! ( I was trying `::BuildConfig.FOO.name` duh!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Tenfour04

`BuildConfig::FOO.name`

`::` is a part of Metaprogramming: https://towardsdatascience.com/kotlin-the-next-frontier-in-modern-meta-programming-8c0ac2babfaa

Combined with `.name` is Reflection:

> The expression ::x evaluates to a property object of type KProperty, which allows us to read its value using get() or retrieve the property name using the name property.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-mutable-property/

[Why getting class in Kotlin using double-colon (::)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339034/why-getting-class-in-kotlin-using-double-colon)