# Kotlin this::variableName - Meaning of the :: operator?

Tags: android, kotlin

I've got this class from a tutorial:

```
package com.mizech.minipaint

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.view.View
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat

class CanvasView(context: Context): View(context) {
    private lateinit var extraCanvas: Canvas
    private lateinit var extraBitmap: Bitmap
    private val backgroundColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources,
        R.color.colorBackground, null)

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)

        if (this::extraBitmap.isInitialized) { // This is the line, which I don't get!
            extraBitmap.recycle()
        }
        extraBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        extraCanvas = Canvas(extraBitmap)
        extraCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor)

    }
}
```

Why isn't it "this.extraBitmap" or just "extraBitmap"? It's a varible, which is defined a class-level. Why is "this" necessary at all?

Put especially: **What's the meaning of the double-semicolon (::) in this specific case?**

Comment: also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339034/why-getting-class-in-kotlin-using-double-colon)

Comment: Making use of the `::` operator, you retrieve additional information, including things such as method references, property references and class literals. In this case, you want to see that the variable you're using has been initialized (it's a lateinit, so it can crash)

Comment: @a_local_nobody Okay. If I get it right, then the :: is used for to retrieve runtime-information about the Bitmap-object?

Comment: basically yes, it allows you to check additional information about something, although it's mostly used in 2 scenarios, either where you're using it to pass a reference of a function to something or in this case where you're doing safety checking for the lateinit variable

Comment: looking at your code briefly, i'm sure there's no difference between `this::extraBitmap.isInitialized` or just using `::extraBitmap.isInitialized`

Comment: no worries, hope it helps